# Commenting in c#

Tags: c#, comments

I have a simple problem.I am new to c# and I wanted to know whether or not to put the author in a .cs class.So far I have seen that only the summary and header comments are put there.

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference, really.

Comment: Quote: `If this code works, it was written by Paul DiLascia. If not, I don't know who wrote it`

Answer (score 3):

There is really no right or wrong answer here - it comes down to company policy/your preference. In my opinion, however, it is unnecessary for two reasons:

- source control tells you this information
- more than one developer can be involved in the development of any one file

Comment: Source control mainly invalidates "last modified" and "last modified by" (but boy, does it invalidate them!). For recording the original author, the main developer or the maintainer, it may have some more merit.

Answer (score 0):

When using a source control system, it is totally irrelevant to put the author as a comment. The source control system can help you to give the person that did the latest change to each single line.

if you're not using source control or are publishing the code on the web a comment could be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like single author, if the codebase is shared. If you have any source control, it would take care of associating each edit information with user. That's a better way to go than having author name at the top and appending each author name when he/she touches that file.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, if you're releasing the code, and you wrote the code, maybe have some updates from someone, you put you as the author, and add notes for the updates/corrections/bug fixes.

If its internal, this shouldnt be necessary as the source control will take care of that, and internally its less important to try and say "this is mine".